# Get index based on a condition in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, histogram

I have a list of cumulative proportions based off of a histogram that I calculated in Google Earth Engine. Now I want to find the index of this list where the value is `>= 0.995` and then use that index to get the appropriate value from `sortedKeys`. Any ideas? Here is my working code...

```
Deforestation = Deforestation.updateMask(Deforestation.neq(0))
var Deforestation_binnedDNF = Deforestation.multiply(DNF)
var rasterBounds = Deforestation.geometry();

var minValue = Deforestation_binnedDNF.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: rasterBounds,  
  scale: 30,          
  maxPixels: 10000000000  
});

var minValue = minValue.get('b1')
print(minValue, 'minValue')

var maxValue = Deforestation_binnedDNF.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: rasterBounds,  
  scale: 30,          
  maxPixels: 10000000000  
});

var maxValue = maxValue.get('b1')
print(maxValue, 'maxValue')

var class_width = 2

// Calculate the number of bins
var num_bins = ee.Number(maxValue).subtract(ee.Number(minValue)).divide(class_width).add(1).floor();
print(num_bins)

// Compute the histogram using reduceRegion.
var histogram = Deforestation_binnedDNF.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram({maxBuckets: num_bins, minBucketWidth: 2}),
  geometry: Deforestation.geometry(),
  scale: 30, // Adjust the scale as needed.
  maxPixels: 1e13 // Adjust the maxPixels as needed.
});

histogram = ee.Dictionary(histogram.get('b1'))
var sortedKeys = histogram.get('bucketMeans')
print('Sorted Keys:', sortedKeys)
var sortedCounts = histogram.get('histogram')

// Convert bin values and counts to ee.Arrays
var binValuesArray = ee.Array(sortedKeys);
var binCountsArray = ee.Array(sortedCounts);

// Compute cumulative sum of histogram counts using ee.Array.accum
var cumulativeCountsArray = binCountsArray.accum(0, 'sum');

// Convert cumulativeCountsArray to a list
var cumulativeCounts = cumulativeCountsArray.toList();
print('Cumulative Sum:', cumulativeCounts)

var sumDeforestation = ee.Number(cumulativeCounts.get(-1));
print('Sum Actual Deforestation (pixels)', sumDeforestation)

var cumulativeProp = cumulativeCounts.map(function(count) {
  return ee.Number(count).divide(sumDeforestation);
});
print('Cumulative Proportions:', cumulativeProp)

// Define the target cumulative proportion.
var targetCumulativeProp = 0.995;
```

[Link to full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/eb90e94f4882b5bdc9d8ff05c7d67477)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of a value based on condition, first, a filter is necessary. The `ee.Filter.gte()` is appropriate according to your requirement. This will return a list of all values that satisfy the condition.

Secondly, by applying `indexOfSublist()`, the starting position of the first occurrence in the filtered list will be returned. Finally, you can get the value from the sortedKeys list using the index.

```js
var index = cumulativeProp.indexOfSublist(cumulativeProp.filter(ee.Filter.gte('item',0.995)))
var value = ee.List(sortedKeys).get(index)
```